# Java heap space (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError) Exception when i build ejb module on Netbean6.9.1

Tags: ejb, netbeans-6.9, java-5

> The system is out of resources. Consult the following stack trace for
>   details. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

[image]

I have also updated this prems to 
-Xmx1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m

but still face same exception here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Currently I have changed the Java plat from jdk 1.5 to Jdk 1.6 in Netbean properties
```

[image]

> Now EJB build successfully.

Comment: I have changed the Java Platform jdk 1.5 to jdk 1.6, but did not know the actual reason on jdk1.5.. Anyone can help me appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing memory of netbeans.

In the etc directory under your Netbeans-Home, edit the file netbeans.conf file. -Xms and -Xmx should be increased to the values that allow your program to compile.

Here are the instructions in netbeans.conf:

- Note that default -Xmx and -XX:MaxPermSize are selected for you
  automatically. You can find these values in var/log/messages.log file
  in your userdir. The automatically selected value can be overridden
  by specifying -J-Xmx or
  -J-XX:MaxPermSize= here or on the command line.

Put the values in the netbeans_default_options string.

Comment: -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=200m   :
replace with
-J-Xms512m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=200m

now netbean is not opened.